Does weather affect the fish you catch?
Does the weather affect the type of fish you catch in WEBFISHING? It got foggy and started raining while I was fishing.


The rain affects the type of fish, yes, but other kinds of weather have their own affects too.
According to the wiki,
Meteors:

Meteor spawns are a special event that cause a Meteor to fall in a random body of water somewhere on the map. When a meteor spawns, it plays a faint whooshing sound for around a second before landing in the water and playing a loud splashing sound. When in close proximity to a meteor, the clicking sound of a Geiger counter can be heard.
When the player casts their rod on a meteor spot, catch chance is increased by 500%, and the player is guaranteed to hook an Unidentified Fish Object (provided the Fresh Lure, Salty Lure, or Magnet Lure are not equipped).
A meteor will despawn after a fish has been caught from it, or after 120 seconds.

Rain:

Rain is a randomly-occuring event that causes a large raincloud to spawn over the map. Rainclouds spawn in a random location, and slowly drift through the center of the map over the course of around 9 minutes. When standing under the rain cloud, a rain particle effect appears and the air becomes noticably foggier. In addition to the visual effects, fishing in rain allows the player to catch unique rain fish.

And these rain fish are specifically:

Anomalocaris
Helicoprion
Horseshoe crab
Leedsichthys

